# how to replace string between 2 chars with newline in python

Tags: python, string

I want to remove the data between single quotes i.e. avcd

a = 'avcd';

I am using this code. Although, i am getting the the text data from a text file.

```
text = 'acbnmmff hjkki.
    It is recommended'

r = re.sub(r"= '.*?';", '', text.rstrip('\r\n'))
```

My code is working fine but when the text contains any newline, then it fails at the new line.

How can i make it work

Comment: Fails how? Make what work?

Comment: do you get an exception? which one?

Comment: When i try to replace the data in the text variable, then only **acbnmmff hjkki.** gets replaced. Similarly when i try to get the data between ' and '; then i only gets **acbnmmff hjkki.** not the whole string.

Comment: replace newlines with something else and put them back afterward.

Comment: If you're going to insist on using regular expressions for this, then I'm pretty sure you'll need to add the `re.MULTILINE` flag to your regular expression. https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the misconception that `.` matches everything in python. But it doesn't match new lines unless you specify the `re.DOTALL` flag. You can use it in your case like this:

```
r = re.sub(r"= '.*?';", '', text.rstrip('\r\n'), flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `r = re.sub(r"= '.*?';", '', text.rstrip('\r\n'), flags=re.DOTALL)`

Comment: string to replace is unknown. It comes dynamically.

Comment: So what? For example: `a` is the substring to be replaced and `b` is the new substring (where a & b are variable). You may use it like: `r = text.replace(a, b)`

Comment: I dont know what is a. I just know that whatever is there between = ' and '; to be replaced with _null_. How the above code be used ?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your problem. Then you have to use regex. You can achhieve that by: `r = re.sub(r"= '.*?';", '', text.rstrip('\r\n'). re.DOTALL)` For matching new lines, DOTALL flag is required